# jQuery/Foundation: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'hover'

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

The following code (Foundation 4, jQuery)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#important img").hover(function() {
      alert("");
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Gives the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'hover'

Usually this error is caused by a missing $ but not in this case?

**EDIT:** here's how the foundation 4 html looks like at the end of body:

```
<script>
document.write('<script src=' +
('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') +
'.js><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.alerts.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.clearing.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.joyride.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>
```

**EDIT 2: Solution**

Solved this by including jQuery in the head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

The actual jQuery code is the same:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#important img").hover(function() {
      alert("");
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: @MohammadAdil If that were true, it wouldn't be complaining about the **method**

Comment: Are you also using `prototype.js` on your page? Or does foundation (not sure what that is) use `$`? Try using `jQuery("#important img")` instead, to see if `$` is being overwritten

Comment: Ok, is there some HTML?

Comment: `$` is most likely not `jQuery` on your page.

Comment: I'm using the default Foundation template so it's hard to say what it actually inserts because there's lots of things going on behind the scenes. If I try using jQuery() I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Please see update to my question

Comment: Why are you doing `('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery')`?  The problem is probably that you are loading zepto, which doesn't have `.hover`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's default in their documentation of "how to use Foundation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other library might use `$`, meaning that it's possibly overwriting jQuery's `$` instance. Because of that, when you use `$`, it's referring to the other library, which doesn't seem to have the `.hover()` method.

You can either use `jQuery` instead of `$` to reference the jQuery library, or use `jQuery.noConflict();` to make the jQuery library accessible in a different variable - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Of course, make sure you include the jQuery library on your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

otherwise `jQuery` won't even be defined.

Comment: Foundation includes jQuery at the end of the page. Do I need to include it again and, if so, in the head of the document?

Comment: @Antwerp Is your page too big that you can't post it? You only need to include jQuery once, anyways

Comment: I solved this by explicitly adding jquery to the head. Might cause trouble later on but it will have to do for now. Please see update.

Comment: @Antwerp I'm wondering if it's because of your code `document.write('<script src=' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'js/vendor/zepto' : 'js/vendor/jquery') + '.js><\/script>')` because it can't find the jQuery library. You know that you need to have a JavaScript file called "jquery.js" in the directory "js/vendor/jquery", right? If you include jQuery on the page separately, you might be able to take that line out

Comment: that's just default Foundation code that comes with the starter template file. Dunno why it's actually needed.

Comment: @Antwerp Yeah, I saw that in their docs. It's just their way of dynamically adding jQuery (or Zepto) to the page. Try removing it. If things still work, I was right, and you can leave it out. Otherwise, keep it in I guess :)